# Do I need to put data in redux store when I need 'em only on main page?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm writing an app using reactjs. On a main page I want to display some articles, poll and other necessary data. Do I need to put that in redux store? I wonder if its necessary. I won't use this exact same data in any other component. These will be thumbnails of articles with links to the full version (another component where im gonna fetch single article data based on ID).

example:
`Home page route: /`
`Article route: /news/:id/...`

Comment: Local state in your component will be sufficient for your task. Mainly we use Redux when we want to communicate data and events between distant components. I don't see a need for this in your task because the only data transferred across to the new page is an id which is already sent in the URL.

Comment: thanks for your time